# std::all_of produces more code than simple for loop

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a simple use-case for checking if elements of a container are non-zero.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool true_on_any_nonzero(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for(const auto& elem : v)
    {
        if(elem != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

bool true_on_any_nonzero(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    return std::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i) { return i != 0; });
}
```

Using clang 16.0.0 with -O3 (godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/rjbsrfT71), the `all_of` version produces significantly more code than the simpler for loop. Am I using it incorrectly, or is this expected? I was hoping to refactor some of my code to use modern features from the library, but this particular API seems to not provide as many benefits in terms of code size. Happy to be corrected!

Comment: code size is not a good measure of performance.  use a tool like google benchmark and profile the code to see which one is actually faster.

Comment: Looks to me like `all_of` was subject to more partial loop unrolling. Intuitively, it should be faster. Benchmark to confirm.

Comment: You can also benchmark your code here: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: And before benchmarking, consider that all_of is not the same as any_of.  :-)

Comment: The second function checks that **every** element is non-zero. The first checks whether **any** element is non-zero. So they're doing two different things. To make the second one do what the first does, change `all_of` to `any_of`.

Comment: With @PeteBecker's change https://quick-bench.com/q/v3hh4Of7rPzCsZv2r3khmEZ2Snc - in this test, _all_ are 0 so ... not a conclusive test I admit

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! @PeteBecker I must admit the truth table for any/all will take some time for me to understand, thank you for the correction. Thank you Ted for the benchmark. I added some non-zero elements and the any_of version is faster

Comment: That looks suspiciously as if `all_of` is implemented via `std::find_if`. And that uses explicit loop unrolling in its template code

Comment: @rookie, it is simple: *all* => *and*, *any* => *or*. So for *all*  a single `false` determines the result, while for *any* one single `true` decides. *not any* == *all not* and *not all* == *any not*. Just like basic theorems in digital design.